# Left Join not returning Null or Non-matching values

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to return all values from PF_OUTPUT where the token ID equals "AdmissionInfo" as well as the matching results from PF_RESULTS just for PAT_SEQ = 105566168.

I've looked at some other questions and I have included the null statement within the Left join where clause, however it still is just returning matching values.

```
    SELECT CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.TOKEN_NAME,
  CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.DISPLAY_SEQ,
  CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.RES_SEQ,
  CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.LABEL_SEQ,
  CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.DISPLAY_RESULT_NAME,
  CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.OUTPUT_RESULT_NAME,
  CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.OUTPUT_FIELD_NAME,
  PF_RESULTS.PERFORM_DDT,
  PF_RESULTS.CHART_DDT,
  PF_RESULTS.STAFF_SEQ,
  PF_RESULTS.RESULT_VALUE,
  PF_RESULTS.STATUS,
  PF_RESULTS.PF_RESULTS_SEQ,
  PF_RESULTS.PAT_SEQ,
  PF_RESULTS.PF_RESULT_SEQ,
  PF_RESULTS.RECORD_VERSION,
  PF_RESULTS.LABEL_SEQ AS LABEL_SEQ1
FROM CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT
LEFT JOIN PF_RESULTS
ON CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.LABEL_SEQ      = PF_RESULTS.LABEL_SEQ
AND CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.RES_SEQ       = PF_RESULTS.RES_SEQ
WHERE (CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.TOKEN_NAME = 'AdmissionInfo'
AND PF_RESULTS.PAT_SEQ            = 105566168)
OR (CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.TOKEN_NAME    = 'AdmissionInfo'
AND PF_RESULTS.PAT_SEQ           IS NULL)
ORDER BY CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.TOKEN_NAME,
  CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.DISPLAY_SEQ
```

Comment: Include the PAT_SEQ = 105566168 filter in the "on ..." clause and not the "where ..."

Answer (score 1):

Move PF_RESULTS.PAT_SEQ            = 105566168 line from your where condition to your ON clause of the join.

```
    SELECT CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.TOKEN_NAME,
  CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.DISPLAY_SEQ,
  CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.RES_SEQ,
  CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.LABEL_SEQ,
  CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.DISPLAY_RESULT_NAME,
  CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.OUTPUT_RESULT_NAME,
  CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.OUTPUT_FIELD_NAME,
  PF_RESULTS.PERFORM_DDT,
  PF_RESULTS.CHART_DDT,
  PF_RESULTS.STAFF_SEQ,
  PF_RESULTS.RESULT_VALUE,
  PF_RESULTS.STATUS,
  PF_RESULTS.PF_RESULTS_SEQ,
  PF_RESULTS.PAT_SEQ,
  PF_RESULTS.PF_RESULT_SEQ,
  PF_RESULTS.RECORD_VERSION,
  PF_RESULTS.LABEL_SEQ AS LABEL_SEQ1
FROM CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT
LEFT JOIN PF_RESULTS
ON CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.LABEL_SEQ      = PF_RESULTS.LABEL_SEQ


   AND CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.RES_SEQ       = PF_RESULTS.RES_SEQ

 AND PF_RESULTS.PAT_SEQ            = 105566168

    WHERE (CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.TOKEN_NAME = 'AdmissionInfo')
    OR (CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.TOKEN_NAME    = 'AdmissionInfo'
    AND PF_RESULTS.PAT_SEQ           IS NULL)
    ORDER BY CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.TOKEN_NAME,
      CCDEV.PF_OUTPUT.DISPLAY_SEQ
```

When you include a column from the RIGHT table of your LEFT join you essentially eliminate the LEFT join and make it an inner join.  Unless you are saying where RIGHTTable.column IS NULL.

Comment: Thanks this works! It was so simple... i think I've just been staring at it for too long!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the left-joined table in the where clause. This effectively makes it an inner join since any record that doesn't exist wil always yield false.

Unless of course the check in the where clause includes an 'is null' check.

You should move the `PF_RESULTS.PAT_SEQ = 105566168` check to the `on` clause of the `left join` to fix this.